# The function must be called several times before it is received

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 ant+ USB sticks
1 simulate a device that can share data. (Simulation software[SimuAnt])
1 simulate the display to show the data. (windows PC the unity application)

All working fine, but only 1 thing is weird.

i have checked that with a Debug.Log that the function is really called.
I use a button for it.

Now the weird stuff is: when i clicked the button, the debug log confirm that the page is send to device.
but i have no effect in the device.
When i click rapidly the button, it works sometime.

When i call the function 40 times in code, it works. But i dont think thats the right way to solve the problem.

```cs
public void SetTrainerResistance(int resistance) {
        if (!connected)
            return;
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

        AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
        using (AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.ant.plugin.Ant_Connector")) {
            using (AndroidJavaObject activity = javaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mContext")) {
                activity.Call("Set_fitness_Resistance",resistance);
            }
        }
#else
        pageToSend = new byte[8] { 0x30, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, (byte)(resistance * 2) };//unit is 0.50%
        deviceChannel.sendAcknowledgedData(pageToSend);
#endif
```

I call the function for example with:

```cs
public void FitnessButton2() {
        GameObject.Find("FitnessEquipmentDisplay").GetComponent<FitnessEquipmentDisplay>().SetTrainerResistance(50);
    }
```

i have tried to use a key press instead of a button but it have the same issue.

The complete script is also here:
https://github.com/vrmedialab2017/SharkPrototype/blob/master/CubeTestVR/Assets/AdvancedAnt/Scripts/FitnessEquipmentDisplay.cs

I suspect a synchronization error!?

Anybody have an idea for this weird stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the Frequency of the ant+ devices are the key.
I send in an update function the slope of the track to the SimulationSoftware

But the ant devices working with 4 Hz, so it is just luck if another message goes through.

Now i send the slope every one second (1 Hz)
So my button works now how expected